# We have $4$ letters ($7$ a's, $8$ b's, $5$ c's $4$ d's). How many strings can we form if 'ca' must not appear in them?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have $4$ letters ($7$ a's, $8$ b's, $5$ c's $4$ d's). How many strings can we form if 'ca' must not appear in them?

Using **$a$**'s, **$b$**'s and **$d$**'s we have $\frac{19!}{7!8!4!}$ permutations without having any limitation.

We have 19 letters which form 20 slots between them (like: $|a|b|b|a|\dots|d|a|$).

We can't put **$c$** before an **$a$**, so we have 13 slots left for putting **$c$**.

The different ways of arranging the 5 **$c$** letters is: ${{13+5-1}\choose{5}}$

**The question:**

Will we calculate the sum of $\frac{19!}{7!8!4!}$ and ${{13+5-1}\choose{5}}$, or their multiplication and why? (I know that the first case ($\frac{19!}{7!8!4!} + {{13+5-1}\choose{5}}$) means only one of them can happen, second ($\frac{19!}{7!8!4!} × {{13+5-1}\choose{5}}$) means both can happen. My vote is the second although they tell me the first is the correct).

Comment: Your vote is correct. For each of the $\frac{19!}{7!8!4!}$ permutations of the $a$’s, $b$’s, and $d$’s, you can put the $5$ $c$’s into any of the $13$ available slots, so you must multiply the two numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In combinatorial problems, if we have $y$ objects, and **for each** of them we can build onto them in $x$ ways, then we use multiplication.

As an illustrative example, if we had $y$ boxes, and **each** box contained $x$ objects, we would have $yx$ objects in total.

In this case, we have $\binom{19}{7,8,4}=\frac{19!}{7!\ 8!\ 4!}$ configurations of the letters $a,b,d$.  **For each** of them we can place the letters $c$ in $\binom{13+5-1}{5}$ ways.

Comment: Can you check your first formula?

Comment: It's the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients), which is the same as your formula.

Answer (score 3):

If you think about it, you will see that each different way of arranging the $a,b,d$  leads to a situation in which you can put each of the $c$'s into one of the thirteen slots.

Because this applies to each arrangement of $a,b,d$ you need to multiply the two numbers together - the number of arrangements times the number of possibilities for each arrangement - to get the total number of possibilities.